# Check multiple $_POST with preg_match

Tags: php, post, preg-match

Just a small question about the correct formating of the `preg_match` function for checking my multiple inputs (username, password and captcha)

basically the code is working for all three inputs but I'am not sure of the "correct" way to use ist. I just want to know if there is a different between `,$var1 or $var2 or $var3` or `,$var1 ,$var2 ,$var3`

Its working with both codes so Iam a bit confused if one is "better" or this doesnt matter. Or one is the more "cleaner" version.

```php
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z._ ]{1,12}$/",$_POST['username'] ,$_POST['password'] ,$_POST['captcha_code'])) {
        die();
        }
```

and the other working code is:

```php
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z._ ]{1,12}$/",$_POST['username'] or $_POST['password'] or $_POST['captcha_code'])) {
        die();
        }
```

Comment: Now's the right time to read up on [user-defined functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), but also why constraining allowed password characters makes things less secure. (I'm assuming you also should investigate password hashing, and SQL parameter binding. Kinda always the case with such type of questions..)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Password is allready hashed in the sql table. I also use a different database login for storing my user data. 
Also thanks for the tip about parameter binding. I will have a look at it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match three strings with one pattern you can try this code.

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z._ ]{1,12}$/";
if(!preg_match($pattern, $_POST['username'])
   or !preg_match($pattern, $_POST['password'])
   or !preg_match($pattern, $_POST['captcha_code'])) {
   die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work great. I've also make use of KIKO Software's tip and added numbers to the allowed characters and changed my pass in the sql datatable. :) Hope you have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `$var1 or $var2 or $var3` is obviously completely wrong. You cannot `or` strings and expect a decent result. In most cases the result will be `true`, which is not what you want.

This makes me doubt your statement: "Its working with both codes".

And yes, if I check the manual for [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) it is obvious that it doesn't accept multiple subjects separated by commas.

So both versions **do not work**.

On top of that is a more general issue. You're trying to use `preg_match()` to restrict the possible content of the variables to between 1 and 12 characters out of `"a-zA-Z._"`. That is very restrictive. It is considered *bad practice* to restrict usernames and passwords like this.

You also just `die();` when not pattern match was found, that's not very informative to the user.

So the "cleaner" version is to leave out this code.

Sorry, that I cannot be more positive... Perhaps a hint will help?

Have a look at [filter_input()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), it is what I use nowadays to filter input.

Comment: Yes you are right. I've checked this further and this isnt really "working". It was just looking at the first. You dont need to be sorry, really. I'am new to php since a week. And I still dont know many basics, so this is okay. Even through comments like this I learn alot. So thank you for your time. I will have a look at the filter_input() 

The reason why I use die(); is because this login is only for my personal dashboard I currently build. So I dont want to give any informations to anyone if the login failed because Iam the only one who has an login. So there is no reason for it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ( ['username','password','captcha_code'] as $key ) {
    if ( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z._ ]{1,12}$/", $_POST[$key]) ) {
        die();
    }
}
```